# Non blocking Mutex side effect?

Tags: c#, multithreading, mutex

The idea behind my code is I want to loop through this list and I only want to process 4 loops at a time. No problem I can copy/paste code i wrote earlier. Oops, I need a resource (wc) and it cant be shared. So I have 4 of them one for each thread!

It didn't go as I expected. There is no trylock so I used WaitOne(0) which should not block as [the docs say](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189907.aspx). However I am able to get my exception which shows index==-1 which shouldnt happen imo.

Why is it happening

```
var s = new Semaphore(0, 4);
s.Release(4);

var wcs = new MyObject();
var mutexs= new Mutex[4];
for (int i = 0; i < wcs.Count(); ++i)
{
    wcs[i] = new MyObject();
    mutexs[i] = new Mutex();
}

int counter = 0;
Parallel.ForEach(ls, v =>
{
    s.WaitOne();
    int index = -1;
    try
    {
        ++counter;
        Console.WriteLine("Counter = " + counter.ToString());
        MyObject wc = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < mutexs.Count(); ++i)
        {
            if(mutexs[i].WaitOne(0))
            {
                index = i;
                wc = wcs[i];
            }
        }
        if (index == -1)
            throw new Exception("this triggers");
        //...
    }
    finally
    {
        --counter;
        mutexs[index].ReleaseMutex();
        s.Release();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first thread is taking up all the Mutex, you need a "break;" inside of your " if(mutexs[i].WaitOne(0))" statement

```
var s = new Semaphore(0, 4);
s.Release(4);

var wcs = new MyObject();
var mutexs= new Mutex[4];
for (int i = 0; i < wcs.Count(); ++i)
{
    wcs[i] = new MyObject();
    mutexs[i] = new Mutex();
}

int counter = 0;
Parallel.ForEach(ls, v =>
{
    s.WaitOne();
    int index = -1;
    try
    {
        ++counter;
        Console.WriteLine("Counter = " + counter.ToString());
        MyObject wc = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < mutexs.Count(); ++i)
        {
            if(mutexs[i].WaitOne(0))
            {
                index = i;
                wc = wcs[i];
                break; //Use only one Mutex per thread
            }
        }
        if (index == -1)
            throw new Exception("this triggers");
        //...
    }
    finally
    {
        --counter;
        mutexs[index].ReleaseMutex();
        s.Release();
    }
});
```

Comment: Oh crap! oops. ugh. Well. That sounds about right. Accepted and i'll give you bonus rep in a few days when it lets me set a bounty ;P